# nginx rewriting brackets in reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, brackets

We just discovered in a reverse proxy setup that nginx is rewriting URL-encoded brackets as real brackets in proxy requests. For example, https://foo/a/b/test%20%5BTEST%5D.png gets rewritten to /a/b/test%20[TEST].png when it's proxied to the backend.

My config is very simple:

```
    location /a/b/ {

    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8082/;

    proxy_connect_timeout   15s;
    proxy_send_timeout      60s;
    proxy_read_timeout      60s;

    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass_header       Referer;
    proxy_pass_header       User-Agent;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    client_max_body_size    1024m;
}
```

The incoming request in access log is:

```
172.16.141.8 - - [13/May/2021:10:07:37 -0400] "GET /a/b/test%20%5BTEST%5D.png HTTP/1.1" 400 800 "https://[referrer]" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
```

Upstream log shows:

```
172.16.141.8 - - [13/May/2021:10:07:37 -0400] "GET /a/b/test%20%5BTEST%5D.png HTTP/1.1" 400 1386 127.0.0.1:8082
```

And the network trace of the request at port 8082 (the target of the proxy) is:

```
10:07:37.903863 IP 127.0.0.1.53518 > 127.0.0.1.8082: Flags [P.], seq 1:2308, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 276559597 ecr 276559597], length 2307
E.      7.y@.@..E.............6.........V.,.....
.{...{..GET /a/b/test%20[TEST].png HTTP/1.0
X-Real-IP: 172.16.141.8
X-Forwarded-For: 172.16.141.8
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Host: localhost:8082
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: https://[referrer]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Why is nginx rewriting the encoded brackets as actual brackets? It's not touching the space in the URL, so it's definitely being selective as to what it rewrites for some reason. I'm running nginx version 1.16.1.

Thanks!

Comment: The brackets in that location of the URI have no special meaning, therefore both of the URIs (the one with encoded brackets and the one with actual brackets) are the same according to RFC7230.

Comment: Perhaps the same according to RFC7230, but my application (BrXM) fails on it.... So I'd still love to see a mechanism to see this behaviour disabled as well...